# Faster way to modify gzip xml file (Adobe Premiere Pro project file) in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, gzip, lxml

This is my first post to the stackoverflow community after several years of lurking around and playing with python in my spare time. I've written a script to modify Adobe Premiere Pro files in order to downgrade them to "Version 1". This allows users to open new project files in older versions of the program.

Now, to clear, this has been done before. There are several people on stackoverflow and the Adobe forums who have posted questions and solutions to this problem. My question relates to the speed/efficiency of using the python gzip module and BeautifulSoup with the lxml parser to decompress and modify the xml file.

Here's the code:

```
# Assume I've done all the imports like gzip, bs4, pathlib, sys, etc.
#
def downgrade(prproj_in):  # Main functionality of the program. Downgrades target prproj files.
"""
Shortened the docstring to save reading...
"""
new_version = '1'
root, ext = os.path.splitext(prproj_in)  # Checking if file extension is correct.
new_name = (root + '_DOWNGRADED' + '(v.' + str(new_version) + ').prproj')

try:
    if ext != '.prproj':
        print('Invalid filetype. Must have valid .prproj extension.')
        # If not a valid Adobe Premiere file, exit.
    elif os.path.exists(new_name):
        print('Output file already exists at this location. Please move or rename.')
    else:  # Otherwise... continue on to unzip and parse the xml file with BeautifulSoup.
        with tqdm(total=100) as pbar:  # Initialize progress bar.
            with gzip.open(prproj_in, 'rt') as f:  # Decompress project file and open...
                file_content = f.read()  # Put file contents into variable as string text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(file_content, 'xml')  # create soup object
                print('Current project version: ' +
                      soup.Project.find_next()['Version'])  # Printing current project version.
                soup.Project.find_next()['Version'] = new_version  # Change project version number to 1
                print('Downgraded project version to: ' +
                      str(soup.Project.find_next()['Version']))  # Print new current version.
                pbar.update(80)
                with gzip.open(new_name, 'wt') as f_out:
                    f_out.write(str(soup))  # Turn soup object to string for final writing to gzip file.
                    pbar.update(100)
                    print('Downgrade Complete. New file: ' + new_name)  # Change file extension.
except:
    exception = sys.exc_info()
    handle_exceptions(exception[0])
```

And here is the beginning of the decompressed .prproj file, with the relevant attribute I need to modify:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <PremiereData Version="3">
        <Project ObjectRef="1"/>
        <Project ObjectID="1" ClassID="62ad66dd-0dcd-42da-a660-6d8fbde94876" Version="30">
```

This code runs fine on project files that are only a few MB (before being decompressed), but takes up to 10 minutes to run once the file sizes get up to 60, 70, or 80 MB. I'm currently working on an indy documentary where my project files are over 100 MB when compressed, and up to 1.6 GB when decompressed. I'm running this script on a an iMac Pro with 128 GB of RAM and  a 3 GHz Xeon processor.

I've tested a couple other scripts floating around on GitHub, and they appear to exhibit similar behavior when working with large project files.

Would love to hear some thoughts about how to tackle this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly (correct me if I'm wrong), you want to change a part in the beginning of a gzipped file.

If this is correct, it doesn't matter much that the uncompressed version of the file is an XML file.  The only thing that matters is that you want to change a bit in the beginning of a compressed file.

This is always hard to achieve.  The compression algorithms store later information based on the earlier information, so changing *just* the beginning will change also the later parts, or to put it the other way around:  Changing a part in the beginning makes it necessary to also change the rest of the compressed file in order to not change the rest of the uncompressed version of the file.

In your case I fear you will have to uncompress the whole file, change it, and compress it again.  To avoid this, you would need to change the architecture of your project so that the beginning and the rest of the file are stored separately from each other, e. g. in two different files.  The using software then would need to stitch the two files together when the XML information is needed.

If you go for the first option and uncompress→change→recompress the file, then you can do this by piping which allows you to do this in one step.  Feel free to ask another question on this topic (and link from a comment here to the new question then) if you want some more advice.

Answer (score 1):

@Alfe, thanks for your thoughts! I was able to fix the issue myself by re-writing the xml parsing step using regular expressions. I had not dived into regular expressions before this point, but I've found that it runs an order of magnitude faster than the Beautiful Soup parser.

My revised code is on github:
https://github.com/snorkem/prproj_downgrade/blob/master/prproj_downgrade.py